# Post action jquery for specific php function

Tags: php, jquery, post

I have PHP function for user account login. Now I´m trying to do jquery version in pop-up login.

I got this script:

```
$("#loginbtn").click(function() {
    var name = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    if (name == "" || password == ""){
        alert("Wrong");
    } else{
        $.post("PortalLoginController.php",{ email1: name, password1:password})
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'PortalLoginController.php',
            data: {action: 'xxx'},
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
            }
```

All I want to do is call a specific function in my php file ("xxx") and submit inserted name and password.

PHP script "LoginController" and it´s function (one of more functions in a file)

```
 /**
     * @ApiAction
     */
    public function xxx() {

    $form = $_POST['email1'];
    $form = $_POST['password1'];
    $this->data["form"] = $form;
    ......and here continue try catch block for the form (it works good)
```

So to sum up, how to specify concreate name of php file function in jquery code and how to save both parameters to form variable in php method.

I tried to search a solution, but nothing worked for me in my mvc structure :-)
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

change your jquery cide with this code.

```
$("#loginbtn").click(function() {
    var name = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    if (name == "" || password == ""){
        alert("Wrong");
    } else{
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'PortalLoginController.php',
            data: {email1:name,password1:password,action: 'xxx'},
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
               }
           });
     }
```

Comment: i dont see any difference from the OP

Answer (score 0):

This is the great method try this after validation:

```
$.post('PortLoginController.php',{email1:name,password1:password},function(data){
 alert(data); // You can perform action on condition base such redirecting to another page etc.
});
```

You also encrypt the data variable to be posted on php code by using app.js and app.min.js library...